# Contar apariciones MySQL

Tags: mysql

Esta seria mi tabla llamada `numeros` con sus columnas llamadas `N1 N2 N3 N4` y sus respectivos `numeros` en cada columna.

Lo que no logro hacer es que me cuente la cantidad de veces que salio cada `numero` en cada columna.

TABLA DE EJEMPLO:

```
    NUMEROS
---------------
N1   --     N2

1    --     22     
5    --     1  
1    --     12
```

Dado el caso de la tabla que puse arriba como ejemplo la consulta debería arrojar este resultado.

```
   N1                                                              
---------
Numero - Veces que salio  
   1   --    2
   5   --    1


   N2   
---------
Numero - Veces que salio
    22     --   1
    1      --   1
    12     --   1
```

La consulta que estoy utilizando es ésta, pero no me arroja los resultados como quiero:

```
SELECT uno,dos, COUNT(uno) as CantRep1,
COUNT(dos) as CantRep2
FROM jugada
GROUP BY uno,dos
```

`uno` y `dos` serian en el ejemplo `n1` y `n2`.

Comment: Solo deceas obtener las veces que se repiten cada numero?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, seria esta la consulta que necesitas:

```
Select 'N1', N1, count(*) as cnt from numeros group by 1,2
 union 
( Select 'N2', N2, count(*) as cnt from numeros group by 1,2 )
 union 
( Select 'N3', N3, count(*) as cnt from numeros group by 1,2 )
 union 
( Select 'N4', N4, count(*) as cnt from numeros group by 1,2 )
```